# Incognito recovery Android device

Tags: data-recovery

Is it possible to recover credit card information used in incognito mode  on my Android device?
I have tried repeatedly to no avail and actual card stolen it is imperative I get this information...

Comment: no sorry...  its not possible....

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Incognito Help says this —

> Chrome doesn't save your browsing history or information entered in
>   forms. Cookies and site data are remembered while you're browsing, but
>   deleted when you close Incognito mode.

So as far as it goes, no you cannot recover any of the information of your credit card.